# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot create Property 'className' on string 'Message'

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, classname

I am attempting to create the 'Contact Form' by using 'EamilJS' into my webpage that has created in React.js. Everything work fine, but it returns the error when I add the 'dynamic classname'.

The purpose of these Dynamic ClassNames are showing success message once the user message has been sent. (I am referring the Blog: https://placidowang.medium.com/how-to-add-an-email-form-to-your-react-website-for-free-using-emailjs-and-react-hook-form-7267d6365291 )

The error shown when I click the "send" button, but the email still successfully has submitted.

```
Contact.jsx:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property 'className' on string 'Message'
```

```
<h2>Contact</h2>
<p className='status-message' >{statusMessage}</p>
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} id='contact-form'>
...
</form>
```

So, the ClassName of

should updated either "status-message success" or 'status-message'.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    generateContactNumber();
    sendForm('default_service', 'template_anr3xk1', '#contact-form')
      .then(function(response) {
      // ...
      setStatusMessage("Message sent!");
      statusMessage.className = "status-message success";
      console.log(statusMessage);
      setTimeout(()=> {
        statusMessage.className = 'status-message'
      }, 5000)
    }, function(error) {
      // ...
      console.log(statusMessage);
      setStatusMessage("Failed to send message! Please try again later.");
      statusMessage.className = "status-message failure";
      setTimeout(()=> {
        statusMessage.className = 'status-message'
      }, 5000)
    });
  };
```

I tried to useState to add the additional className, like below, but I could not use "+"

```
<p className={"status-message" + (useStateVar && "success")}></p>
```

How can I change the className dynamically if the message has sent successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `useState` solution at the end is fine, you just forgot to add a space after `status-message` so it made it one class of `status-messagesuccess` instead of `status-message` and `success`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Yes, I fortgot to add the space at the end, but I added in to the real code. (just missed the space here) Somereason, I could not use the "+" simbol. It returns the error if I added the "<p className={"status-message " + (useStateVar && "success")}></p>"

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @DemiPixel Hey, You are right. I missed curly bracket "{}". Now it works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class name you can also replace the way of calling the className, example for this line:

```
statusMessage.className = "status-message failure";
```

instead of calling ***className*** , you should use ***attributes*** such as this line.

```
statusMessage.attributes['class'].value = "status-message failure";
```